# Critical section in method get-set. How to use semaphor? - JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading

how can i use mutex or some semaphore in method get/set?
I have 2 threads (`A, B`)..

Thread `A` read from server and update `matrix` and `B` is printing `matrix`.

In pseudo java:

```
some class {
     matrix[][];
     matrixGet(){
          return matrix.
     }
     matrixSet(matrix[][]){
             //set matrix..
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [read write lock](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/read-write-locks.html) or [synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) in java.